# Caesar Cipher in Java. Encode, decode an rotate a String

Tags: java

Hi, I am trying to make a program, which allows the user to encode, decode and rotate a String. For example:

User Input: "Caesar"
System  Output: "Fdhvdu"

The user may decide how much the word is to be rotated. The program is not finished yet, I just made a method for option V: encode and wanted to know if I made it is appropriate? or if it works completely different way!

```
public class CaesarsChiffre {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        char benutzerBefehl;
        String benutzerText;
        int rotation=0;


        System.out.println("Caesars Chiffre encode, decode, rotate.");
        System.out.println("Waehlen Sie:");
        System.out.println("V for encode");
        System.out.println("E for decode");
        System.out.println("B for rotation");
        benutzerBefehl=V; //Input.readChar();
        System.out.println("Enter text to encode:");
        benutzerText=Input.readString();
        System.out.println("which rotation do you want?");
        rotation=Input.readInt();

        switch (benutzerBefehl){ 
        case V: System.out.println(": Encoded text: "+Caesar.encode(benutzerText,rotation));
            break;
        case E: (": Decoded text: "+Ceasar.decode(benutzerText,rotation));
            break;
        case B: // will be filled
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid option..");
        }

        public static String Caesar.encode(String original_text, int rot){

            String []s= original_text.split(" ");

            for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
                Stringbuilder letter=new StringBuilder();
                letter.append(s.[i]+rot);
            }

            return String;

        }




    }

}
```

Comment: You won't even get that to compile, so to answer your question: no, it's not appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>         for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
>             Stringbuilder letter=new StringBuilder();
>             letter.append(s.[i]+rot);
>         }
> ```

This loop will not work since you create (and dissmiss) the `Stringbuilder` object with *every* iteration of the loop.

BTW: `letter` is the wrong name for the variable since it will contain a *word* (at least) not a single letter...

Comment: What about `s.[i]+rot`?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen ??? this is a single letter added to the string build up in `letter` which currently happens to hold this one and only letter. But it does not make any sense since `letter` lives only for one single iteration and is not used anywhere else. - Do *you* see something else?

Comment: Yes, I see 1) a dot too many and 2) a string concatenated to an int

Answer (score 0):

You need to read something about oop, because you put everything to one single method, this is not java way. When you continue to write code in this way you will suffer and waste big amount of time trying to debug and understand what's going on. In resolving tasks first point is thinking, writing code is the last point. First we need to decomposit task. Caesar cypher is about to shift every letter in sentence to new position from it initial point. So we will create class Letter and *tell* this Letter class to shift itself to right or left.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String word = "Caesar";
        String expected = "Fdhvdu";
        String result = word.chars()
                .mapToObj(character -> new Letter((char) character))
                .map(letter -> letter.shiftRightTo(3))
                .map(letter -> letter.toString())
                .collect(Collectors.joining());
        System.out.println(result.equals(expected));
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}


class Letter {
    private final String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    private final boolean isLowerCase;
    private final char letter;

    public Letter(char letter) {
        this.isLowerCase = Character.isLowerCase(letter);
        this.letter = Character.toLowerCase(letter);
    }

    Letter shiftRightTo(final int shift) {
        int letterPosition = alphabet.indexOf(letter);
        for (int i = 0; i < shift; i++) {
            letterPosition++;
            if (letterPosition == alphabet.length()) {
                letterPosition = 0;
            }
        }
        char shiftedLetter = alphabet.charAt(letterPosition);
        return new Letter(isLowerCase ? shiftedLetter : Character.toUpperCase(shiftedLetter));
    }

    Letter shiftLeftTo(final int shift) {
        int letterPosition = alphabet.indexOf(letter);
        for (int i = 0; i < shift; i++) {
            letterPosition--;
            if (letterPosition == -1) {
                letterPosition = alphabet.length() - 1;
            }
        }
        char shiftedLetter = alphabet.charAt(letterPosition);
        return new Letter(isLowerCase ? shiftedLetter : Character.toUpperCase(shiftedLetter));
    }

    public String toString() {
        char result = isLowerCase ? letter : Character.toUpperCase(letter);
        return Character.toString(result);
    }
}
```

This code works but need to refactor to remove code duplication. You may improve it further to introduce another one class that calls Word and hide existence of Letter class behind it.